# SVG viewBox not correctly work in Chrome but in Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I am working a project by use SVG viewBox, this is a html snippet.

```html
<body>
  <svg width="960" height="960" viewBox="18897158,-480,960,960">
    <g>
      <circle cx="18897482" cy="-94" r="3" fill="#18ff00"></circle>
      <circle cx="18897837" cy="-102" r="3" fill="#18ff00"></circle>
      <line x1="18897482" y1="-94.00" x2="18897837" y2="-102" stroke-width="1" stroke="#18ff00">
      </line>
      <text x="18897660" y="-98" fill="#18ff00" dominant-baseline="middle"
        text-anchor="middle">0.00094mm</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

When this html in Chrome, the line element does not display correctly, but it works in Edge. I want to know is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: Most UAs don't work very well with large numbers. You're asking them to do very high precision arithmetic to render correctly here.

Comment: Strange... If you paste the SVG into [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1000) the line does show, but not if you paste it into https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I tried [codepen.io](https://codepen.io), it also does not work in chrome but works in Edge.

Comment: Now I see that it only worked because I had Chrome set to 90% zoom on CodePen. Back to 100% and the line disappears again...